# The POM for unknown.binary:mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin:jar:SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, pom.xml

Ive been getting the error show in the title when building my project, which i believe is the cause of my errors when trying to run it in tomcat. The POM has been added below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<artifactId>AuctionWebsiteM</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>AuctionWebsiteM</name>
<description>An auction website</description>
<version>1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Web with Tomcat + Embed -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Optional, for bootstrap -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>

            <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>

    </dependency>
             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                    <version>5.2.9.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
  <type>jar</type>
 </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin</artifactId>
                <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
    <repositories>
            <repository>
                    <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
                    <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
                    <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
            </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Hopefully there's something simple that i've missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you modify and include the version information in the dependency information of `mysql-connector`. like below and try again , 
I am hoping maven is unable to download the mysql-connector jar and you can verify this by checking, the jar into external library section of your IDE, where all the jars download by maven will be shown:-

```
 <!--Mysql-Connector-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.36</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, by deleting the 'mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin' from my dependencies folder and adding the specific version as described above the error went away. Unfortunately now im getting new errors when running the project relating to "Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'"

Comment: @HazardAGuess , could you create another question , with the code and complete error details ?

Comment: @HazardAGuess , can you give me a link ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093948/failed-to-start-component-standardenginecatalina-standardhostlocalhost-stan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139379/discussion-between-amitk-and-hazardaguess).

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem when I generated hibernate.cfg.xml in my SpringBoot application using Netbeans IDE. Netbeans adds two dependencies as below when generating the hibernate configuration file-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin</artifactId>
    <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

By deleting these dependencies and adding the following dependencies I could solve the problem.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```