# Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/AuctionWebsite]]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Ive got myself into a bit of a mess when trying to run my project, receiving a list of errors as shown below.

First error shown below-

```
29-Mar-2017 12:59:55.098 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-65] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/AuctionWebsite]]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at com.mkyong.AuctionWebApplication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b523f52f.entityManagerFactory(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:441)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
... 66 common frames omitted
```

Caused by

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernateEntityManagerFactory
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1275) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.0.M17]
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1109) ~[catalina.jar:9.0.0.M17]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:596)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.<init>(HibernateJpaVendorAdapter.java:89) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
... 77 common frames omitted

at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:467)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1617)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor102.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1483)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:904)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:336)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:591)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:319)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:495)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:767)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1347)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The main error point to my AuctionWebApplication.java class which is my configuration -

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories("All")
@EntityScan("All")
public class AuctionWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(AuctionWebApplication.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(AuctionWebApplication.class, args);
}

    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/auctiondb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("toor");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManager.setPackagesToScan("All");

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", "false");
        entityManager.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return entityManager;
    }

}
```

Specifically this line -

```
entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
```

My thinkinking is that its a dependency error but i cant find any problems in POM-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>AuctionWebsiteM</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>AuctionWebsiteM</name>
<description>An auction website</description>
<version>1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Web with Tomcat + Embed -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSTL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Need this to compile JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
        <version>4.6.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Optional, for bootstrap -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.7</version>
    </dependency>

            <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.41</version>
    </dependency>
             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
               <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
               <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                <type>jar</type>
            </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
    <repositories>
            <repository>
                    <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
                    <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
                    <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
            </repository>
    </repositories>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: looks like you are following mkyoung tutorial, can u give me the link of that, so i can locally debug it ?

Comment: Yes thats correct although i added LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean seperately - https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/

Comment: looks like, you have changed the quite some of `pom.xml`, so is your `mvn clean package` is successful ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139379/discussion-between-amitk-and-hazardaguess , `mvn clean package` command resolved the issue, it looks like the **dependency** of  `HibernateEntityManagerFactory` class was missing initially, As **OP** was not using the auto-refresh feature of maven. and when **OP** ran `mvn clean package` command,it had downloaded the required jar, which resolved the issue.